# How to create a self-signed SSL Certificate in linux and what are the modification to do apache ssl conf file after getting ssl?

Tags: linux, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

> I have created a self signed certificate with wrong domain name ,now i have to change that.Is that possible
>
> Is ssl certificate is applicable only if you have domain name or it is applicable IP address also?
>
> If Once downloaded SSL certificate, what are modification to do in apache conf file

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using domain name in machine, i  think it's localhost in your case

if this is for development purpose you then can use self signed cert.

Comment: Can i create free ssl certificate my own (in linux) or i can get it from some websites?

Comment: can i modify or edit the self signed ssl certificate in linux

Comment: Can i create free ssl certificate my own (in linux) or i can get it from some websites? 
**Yes,we can create free ssl certificate**

which can be used for testing purposes 
**yes the self created ssl certificates can be used for testing.**
     
can i modify or edit the self signed ssl certificate in linux –
**Yes you always can**

Comment: You can refer this link also.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWHYP_4.0.0/com.ibm.apimgmt.cmc.doc/task_apionprem_gernerate_self_signed_openSSL.html